# How can I add a span to h3 Element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, let

I'm making a chat and I want to add an avatar pics feature so I figured it might work well with span, but the problem is I don't know how to add the span to the element.

```
let avatar = document.createElement("span");
let userMessage = document.createElement("H3");
avatar.setAttribute(userMessage);
userMessage.innerHTML = username + ": " + message;

//document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(avatar);
document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(userMessage);
userMessage.style.background = color;
userMessage.style.textAlign = "left";
document.getElementById("msg").value = "";
```

Comment: Can you clarify which element you need the `span` in? Also, does the commented out code works for you?

Comment: You've used `appendChild` in the code above to append the `h3` to the `#chat` element. Just do the same with your `span` to append it to the `h3` element.

Comment: Side note: Set the `h3`'s `style` *before* appending it (just move the two lines setting `style` properties above the `appendChild` call above it). Better to get the element in the state you want it before you put it in the DOM.

Comment: Can you add expected html result with snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have div with **id="chat"** and you want to append an `h3` tag in a span and then append the chat `div` so your code will look like this

```js
var username="zulqarnain jalil";
var message ="welcome back, have a nice day";
var color='lightgrey';  
var avatar = document.createElement("span");
var userMessage = document.createElement("h3");
userMessage.innerHTML = username + ": " + message;
userMessage.style.background = color;
userMessage.style.textAlign = "left";
avatar.appendChild(userMessage);
document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(avatar);

//document.getElementById("msg").value = "";
```

```html
<div id="chat">

</div>
```

I have created a chatbot snippet for you, here you can test it

```js
var username="zulqarnain jalil";
function sendMessage()
{
var message =document.getElementById('messagebox').value;
if(message)
{
document.getElementById('messagebox').value='';
var color='lightgrey';  
var avatar = document.createElement("span");
var userMessage = document.createElement("h3");
userMessage.innerHTML = username + ": " + message;
userMessage.style.background = color;
userMessage.style.textAlign = "left";
avatar.appendChild(userMessage);
document.getElementById("chat").appendChild(avatar);
}
else
{
// message empty
}


}
//document.getElementById("msg").value = "";
```

```html
<div id="chatBox">
<div id="chat">
</div>
<div>
<input type="text"  id="messagebox" />
<input type="button" onclick="sendMessage()" value="Send" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the @OP wished to add the `span` to the `h3` element - you have this the other way around

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the `span` as a child of the `H3` element.

I think the best approach to this problem is creating a class `Message`. Initializing that class creates `h3` and `span` with unique ids stored in a variable `id` for future use. The class will also add the `h3` as a child of it's parent element ( what ever it is ), and the `span` as a child of the `h3` element.

```js
var counterText = 0;
var counterAvatar = 0;

class UserMessage {
    constructor(msgTxt, avatar){
        // This block initializes the text message of the user
        // It will also add an id to the tag for future use
        let msgTxt = document.createTextNode(msgTxt);
        
        this.messageID = 'text' + counterText;
        this.message = document.createElement('h3');
        this.message.appendChild(msgTxt);
        this.message.setAttribute('id', this.messageID);
        counterText++;

        // This block creates an img element with the attributes src and id
        this.avatarID = 'avatar' + counterAvatar;
        this.avatar = document.createElement('img');
        this.avatar.setAttribute('src', avatar);
        this.avatar.setAttribute('id', this.avatarID);
        counterAvatar++;

        // This block appends the avatar element to the text and the text to the 
        // chat div.
        let chat = document.getElementById('chat');
        this.message.appendChild(this.avatar);
        chat.appendChild(this.message);
    }
}
```

to initialize a new instance:

```js
var message = new UserMessage("Hello, this is a text message!",'<path/to/avatar>')
```

this is an object oriented aproach.

you could also just append the avatar to the message and the message to the chat.
But I think aproaching the problem in an object oriented way is much better since it will save time in the future when you're updating your app.